# How to add a new Migration without having to delete already existent tables manually?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I made a ASP.Net Core Web application with a User authentication. The `CreateIdentitySchema`Migration has been auto-implemented. I, then, added a new Migration which I tried to update (`Upate-database`). This leads to the error:

> "Table 'AspNetRoles' already exists".

From what I've read on the Internet, one way to go about this is to delete the table 'AspNetRoles' manually or to delete it from the new migration.

I expected the migration to automatically drop tables from old migrations and re-create them using the `Up` and `Down` methods.

Do I really have to manually delete the existing tables (from prior migrations) every time I want to apply a new migration?

Comment: Is the first migration already applied to the database? This scenario seems confusing. The usual is: Add a migration, update the database (either automatically or via a script). That will insert into the Migration History table. Adding a new migration does not affect existing things, unless your new migration changes it.

Comment: Hi, yes the first migration has been applied. After that I added a new migration and try to `update-database`. What exactly do you mean by a migration thats "changing existing things"? Thanks @jpgrassi

Comment: Ah then okay. So what does the second migration contains for the `Up` part? I don't use ASP.NET Identity, so I might be on a loss here but.. I would be surprised to this advice of having to delete something prior to running it.